# how to set block template via xml in magento?

Tags: xml, magento

I am trying to load a block from my custom extension in a tab in product settings in the admin part, but the phtml isn't loading when defined within the xml:

```
<layout>
  <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>prodcal_availability</name>
                <block>prodcal/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
                <template>prodcal/catalog/product/prodcaltab.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

The template `prodcaltab.phtml` seems to load if I call it from within the block like

```
public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('prodcal/catalog/product/prodcaltab.phtml');
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Block you extend, but I assume it is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs`. If you check the function `addTab` it only accepts 2 parameters. The template parameter you use in the XML isn't being accepted.